# If $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \sim \text{Dirichlet}(a_1, a_2, a_3)$, what is the joint distribution of $(X_1, X_2)$?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm confused about how to "marginalize out" $X_3$ here. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are known, then $X_3$ must equal $1 - X_1 - X_2$. Does this mean that the joint density is
$$f(x_1, x_2) \propto x_1^{\alpha_1 - 1} x_2^{\alpha_2 - 1}(1 - x_1 - x_2)^{\alpha_3 - 1}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Dirichlet as well, but with the condition $X_1 + X_2 = 1$.  Thus it is also called Beta.

In other words, the Dirichlet density of the joint variable $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is $$f(x_1, x_2, x_3) \propto x_1^{\alpha_1 - 1} x_2^{\alpha_2 - 1} x_3^{\alpha_3 - 1}, \quad x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1.$$  So the third variable is not really a variable at all; we could write the above equivalently as
$$f(x_1, x_3) \propto x_1^{\alpha_1 - 1} (1 - x_1 - x_3)^{\alpha_2 - 1} x_3^{\alpha_3 - 1}.$$
Then integrating over $x_3 \in [0,1]$ gives the marginal density
$$f(x_1) \propto \int_{x_3 = 0}^{1 - x_1} f(x_1, x_3) \, dx_3.$$  You will recover a beta density, which of course is Dirichlet with density
$$f(x_1, x_2) \propto x_1^{\alpha_1' - 1} x_2^{\alpha_2' - 1}, \quad x_1 + x_2 = 1,$$ where $\alpha_1' = \alpha_1$, and $$\alpha_2' = \alpha_2 + \alpha_3,$$  the proof of which is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't understand what it means for a pair of random variables to have a Beta distribution - isn't this the distribution of a single random variable?

Comment: @TheProofIsTrivium In a Dirichlet distribution with variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$, the sum of the three variables must equal $1$.  So there are really only *two* random components.  Similarly, in a Dirichlet distribution with variables $X_1, X_2$, their sum must equal $1$:  $$X_2 = 1 - X_1.$$  So such a distribution is also Beta.  Analogously, a binomial distribution has PMF $$\binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x},$$ but you could write is as $$\binom{n}{x} p^x q^{n-x},$$ where $q = 1-p$.  And a trinomial distribution has PMF $$\binom{n}{x_1, x_2} p_1^{x_1} p_2^{x_2} (1-p_1-p_2)^{n-x_1 - x_2}.$$

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense now - especially with the Binomial example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why we require that $X_1 + X_2 = 1$? As $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ vary jointly in the $2$-Simplex, $(X_1, X_2)$ will vary in the projection of the $2$-Simplex onto $\mathbb{R}^2$, so I think we will just have that $X_1 + X_2 \leq 1$, no?

Comment: @TheProofIsTrivium If you are referring to my original answer, the reason is because integrating with respect to $x_3$ leaves only the single variable $x_1$:  if you actually perform the integration as I suggested, you will obtain a function proportional to $$x_1^{\alpha_1' - 1} (1 - x_1)^{\alpha_2' - 1}.$$  If you are referring to my earlier comment, **all** Dirichlet distributions must have the sum of the $X_i$ equal to $1$.  So if there are $3$ values, they must add to $1$.  If there are $2$ values, they must add to $1$.

Comment: @TheProofIsTrivium Before you ask any further questions, please perform the following exercise:  Consider the Dirichlet distribution for $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ with parameters $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3) = (2, 3, 5)$; i.e., $$f(x_1, x_2, x_3) \propto x_1 x_2^2 x_3^4, \quad 0 \le x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \le 1.$$  Show this is equivalent to $$f(x_1, x_3) = x_1 (1 - x_1 - x_3)^2 x_3^4, \quad 0 \le x_1 + x_3 \le 1.$$  Finally, show that the marginal density of $X_1$ is $$f(x_1) \propto x_1 (1 - x_1)^7,$$ which is equivalent to $$f(x_1, x_2) \propto x_1 x_2^7, \quad 0 \le x_1 + x_2 \le 1.$$

Comment: @TheProofIsTrivium To be absolutely clear:  When I say "A Dirichlet distribution with values $X_1, X_2, X_3$," I mean that these are the only values for the distribution; and when I say "A Dirichlet distribution with values $X_1, X_2$," I'm not referring to the same distribution as the one with three values.  I'm not saying to just take the third value and discard it.  They are **different distributions**.